# How can I define default empty input content for a function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a customContentViewFunction() that I like give an empty content like {} or EmptyView as default to it, which I do not have to do it in use case, for example I done same thing for color!

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        
        customContentViewFunction(content: Text("hello"), color: .green)
        
       // customContentViewFunction() : << Like this one!
        
    }
    
    
    func customContentViewFunction<Content: View>(content: Content, color: Color = Color.red) -> some View {

        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
 
             content

        }

    }
  
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define another version/signature of the function where it gets passed `EmptyView()` for `content`.

You could either choose to define it with the `color` property still there, or leave that out and let it get set to the default in the original signature.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        customContentViewFunction()
    }
    
    func customContentViewFunction(color: Color = Color.red) -> some View {
        return customContentViewFunction(content: EmptyView(), color: color)
    }
    
    func customContentViewFunction<Content: View>(content: Content, color: Color = Color.red) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since we have no initializer for any functions at all I mean in general case of func, in this kind of situations should we always define multiple functions to get the flexibility?

Comment: Just looking at the heads for lots of Apple's Swift code, you can see there are *often* multiple signatures for functions for flexibility.